# Facebook style navigation bar in android application

Tags: android

I tried the following link https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ActionsContentView At first I was very impress with the application as it was doing as expected. But main thing I notice after a while. That is application is simply calling the different urls on the same web view . That means it is not opening the new activity or screen. I was attempting to open new activity with every button click but this approach is not working as ii I call new activity layout via intent it will shown the new layout on new screen and this screen will go.

Please give me some suggestion so that I can open new activities layout with every click. Is is even possible to do like that or not?

Answer (score 1):

My personal favourite: [SlidingMenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu): just replace fragment in your activity when a menu item selected. This code should help:
[activity](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/fragments/FragmentChangeActivity.java) and [menu fragment](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/fragments/ColorMenuFragment.java)

Comment: I haven’t used the fragments in android,but it make sense to me by using the fragmentation. I I can get some example or start up then it would be helpful

Comment: Check out [Lars Vogell's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html), if you need.